# Access denied to folder

Tags: vb.net, server

In my vb.net project, I want to save a ima in a folder, but I have this error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\192.168.100.1\T-Dev\Docs\AGRFOB6NV0UM835B59MX34KT2.jpg' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at P_ControlDoc46.Controllers.U_controldocController.UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile, String descricao) in C:\Users\Pedro Moreira\Desktop\P_ControlDoc46\Controldoc-trimalhas\P_ControlDoc46\Controllers\U_controldocController.vb:line 146/DocsTeste/AGRFOB6NV0UM835B59MX34KT2.jpg

The code that I use to save the file is the following:

```
        Try

            'Save the Byte Array as Image File.
            Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath(String.Format(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DocsFolder") + "{0}.jpg", fileName))
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            Return RedirectToAction("IndexCreate", "U_controldoc")
        End Try
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Really obvious question: the user under which your code is running has appropriate permissions to that folder?

Comment: The folder has permissions for everyone... and is a virtual directory of the site

Comment: I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be a `\\192.168.100.1\\` in the path unless the virtual directory's physical directory is on what is a network drive wr.t. the server. Is that the case?

Comment: Also, unless it's a formatting issue, the path reported in the exception is `\192.168.100.1\T-Dev\Docs\AGRFOB6NV0UM835B59MX34KT2.jpg`. This doesn't look like a well-formed UNC path to me. Shouldn't there be two slashes at the beginning?